# TS2345: Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript

I try to write autologin function but TS error occurs like that  type undefined is not assignable to type string.
//**const userData =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));**

```
autoLogin(){
      const userData =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));//error code
    }
```

To get data key is 'userData' using localStorage of getItem method

```
// const userData =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
```

Comment: You don't deal with the possibility that there's no data in localStorage for the key userData.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData') || '{}');
```